# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from line after line

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

i am trying to copy data from text file into db with "load data local infile".
the text example:

```
jack
|
hi   
|-
ron
|
whats new
|-
jack
|
ok
|-
ron
|
bye
|-
```

the code i am trying:

```
include 'conect.php'; // conect to DB
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'messages2.txt'
INTO TABLE `conv`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '-'
(name, msg)";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

its only copying the first name to the db.
what is the correct way to do this?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I look at it is:

```
jack|hi|-
ron|whats new|-
jack|ok|-
ron|bye|-
```

So I would try:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '|-'
```

However, since you have carriage returns, you may need either `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '|-\n'
```

Comment: @batz I actually ran your original query on my machine and it loaded in fine.